# Qt UI Closing order

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMainWindow in my project as the center of the GUI and this window can open a new one. I wanted that when the user closes the main window, all the other ones opened by the mais window will close as well.

I tried to place a signal inside the main window's destructor to call the other window `close()` slot but it doesn't work. I could only make this work by making a `closeEvent()` in the main window that will send a signal to the other window close slot.

So my question is, how does Qt handles all of this? If the windows exists, why they cant receive a signal if the main window fires it in it's destructor? I fire other signals in the destructor to other threads and they receive them just fine.

Comment: Why not make the main window a parent to all the other "logical-child" windows of your application? In that case the close of main window will close all the children.

Comment: I made the main window's parent the window's parent...is it just a `this` at the constructor?

Comment: I guess not...I just placed a `this` and the window was rendered inside the main window space

Comment: Use _move_ member function to move the new window in the position you want it to show. Or are you trying to say that you have no second window? In case you use a QWidget derived class as a window (and have a parent for it) you can use _setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);_ (look in the documentation for other options instead _Qt::Window_)

Comment: I just subclassed a QWidget as I found in some documentations...is this wrong?

Comment: No, it's not wrong, just that if you want a QWidget to be a window and still have a parent, it needs to be "told" that it's going to be a new window and not a widget inside the parent window, and that is done with setting a window flag (example Qt::Window), but you didn't told what exactly the problem was, or at least i didn't understood, and that was just a guess.

Comment: Thats fine, I just found a tutorial about it....the main question was not about a problem, I just wanted an explanation about the behavior...why the signal is not sent inside the destructor to the window but its sent to other threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is very simple: the destructor is not invoked at the moment that the window is closed. You have already found out that emitting the signal in `closeEvent` is a solution, so I don't quite see what the problem is.

If you insist on emitting the signal in the destructor, you must do two things:

1. Allocate the widget on the heap.
2. Set the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on the widget.

```cpp
int main() {
  QScopedPointer<MyWidget> widget(new MyWidget);
  widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's not a problem, I just wanted to understand what happens under the hood...I mean, why the signal is not sent to the window but it's sent to other threads.

Comment: I wanted to understand more the way Qt closes the UI, the order of things, but just to close this answer I decided to mark yours as the answer since it covers what was happening. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in the following way:

```
void MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    foreach (QWidget *widget, QApplication::topLevelWidgets()) {
        if (widget != this) { // avoid recursion.
            widget->close();
        }
    }
    e->accept();
}
```

The code above will search and close all top level windows as soon as the main window is closing.

Comment: I guess this is too much since setting the main window as a parent to the other windows will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving this and both ways are working for me :

METHOD 1:
  if you want to delete them when closed, then set the attribute Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose. The children are automatically deleted when the parent is deleted.

For your QMainWindow instance call setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose) method
  Ex: My main.cpp

```
    #include "st.h"
    #include <QtGui/QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  St *w = new St();
  w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
  w->show();
  return a.exec();
    }
```

Also pass the "this" pointer to whatever child windows you are creating.
  But then you have create the QMainWindow instance on the heap and not on the stack otherwise your application will crash.

METHOD 2:

Overload the closeEvent method for your QMainWindow and in that close event method ,call 
 deleteLater() method for all the childs.

```
     void St::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *c)
     {
   m_b->deleteLater();//This is a pushbutton
   odlg->deleteLater();//This is child dialog
       //both are children of QMainWindow

     }
```

Comment: @vahancho will it close all the top level widgets ,even if it is not a child of the main window?

Comment: Yes, it supposed to close all top level widgets. P.S. You comment appears under the wrong post:)