# Understanding the difference between two codes of closeEvent

Tags: qt

As I already referred to this Stack overflow question thread[this Stack overflow question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245121/qt-ui-closing-order), I want to understand the differences between two codes :

```
void MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
    {
        foreach (QWidget *widget, QApplication::topLevelWidgets()) {
        if (widget != this) { // avoid recursion.
            widget->close();
        }
     }
     e->accept();
}

void MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    foreach (QWidget *widget, QApplication::topLevelWidgets()) {
        if (widget != this) { // avoid recursion.
            widget->close();
        }
     }
     e->accept();
    }
    QMainwindow::closeEvent(e);
}
```

I want to know the meaning of line `QMainwindow::closeEvent(e); MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)` in the above code. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This line just calls the superclass function explicitly. When you have different declaration of functions or data members you can specify which one you refer to like this.

Here this function is not implemented in QMainWindow, only in its superclass QWidget and you can see that it just calls `event->accept();` ([source](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#n9677)). That means `QMainwindow::closeEvent(e);` does the same as `e->accept();`.